# Do races affect stats?

Tags: wildstar

Do races effect stats, or are they purely aesthetic?

I was planning on recording my adventures so I want to know what I'm doing going into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Races in wildstar have no affect on your stats or have unique abilities. The developers specifically wanted to avoid that mechanic.